# How to get the number of counts between two dates in R?

Tags: r, date, count, between

I have the following data frame

```
df<-data.frame(id=seq(from = 1, to=100), in= c("01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020",  "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020"...), out=c("02-01-2020",  "20-01-2020", "02-05-2020", "02-04-2020", "02-03-2020"...)
```

I would like to get from that a dataframe which could tell how many unique ids are each day. 
Something like this

```
df2<-data.frame(day=c("01-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "04-01-2020"...), count = c(5,6,1,2,3...))
```

For example imagine we have just two id; id 1 date_in = "01-01-2020" and date out = "08-01-2020", and id 2 date_in = "05-01-2020" and date_out = "25-01-2020". Then the desired dataframe would be the following one:

```
df2= data.frame(day = c("01-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "06-01-2020", "07-01-2020", "08-01-2020", "09-01-2020", "10-01-2020"...), count = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,...))
```

As the id 1 would be the only one between 1-5 Jan the count would be 1, between 5-8 as id 1 and id 2 would be in the count would be 2, and after 8 Jan the count would be just 1 as just id 2 would be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited Answer:**

Thank you for the additional details and clarification. Part of my confusion is not realizing the date format is day-month-year and not month-day-year.

You could try the following using `data.table`. First ensure your dates are `Date` objects (avoid `in` as column name).

You can create sequences of days for each `id`. Then, you can use `uniqueN` on `id` to get number of unique `id` each day.

```
library(data.table)

df$day_in <- as.Date(df$day_in, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
df$day_out <- as.Date(df$day_out, format = "%d-%m-%Y")

setDT(df)[ , .(id = id, day = seq(day_in, day_out, by = "day")), 
           by = 1:nrow(df)][, .(count = uniqueN(id)), .(day)]
```

Alternatively, you could use `tidyverse`. Here you will also create sequences of dates for each `id`, then `group_by` each date, and count unique ids with `n_distinct`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  transmute(id, day = map2(day_in, day_out, seq, by = "1 day")) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(day)) %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(id))
```

**Output**

```
           day count
 1: 2020-01-01     1
 2: 2020-01-02     1
 3: 2020-01-03     1
 4: 2020-01-04     1
 5: 2020-01-05     2
 6: 2020-01-06     2
 7: 2020-01-07     2
 8: 2020-01-08     2
 9: 2020-01-09     1
10: 2020-01-10     1
11: 2020-01-11     1
...
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, day_in = structure(c(18262, 18266), class = "Date"), 
    day_out = structure(c(18269, 18286), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fd59b010ee0>)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the question is to know how many distinct ids are between the two dates. In your method I would just count the id once (the in_date) but I would like to count it all the days that are between the in_date and out_date

Comment: Your answer is almost what I'm looking for but not exactly. I added some clarifications

Comment: @AdriánVallsCarbó Please see edited answer, thank you for clarifying.