# Count the number of entries that fall within a range of dates in a separate dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of rows in df1, which contains the date of an event,

```
df1 = data.frame(date = c("2021-07-31", "2021-08-01", "2021-08-12", "2021-08-14"))
```

that fall within the start and end dates of df2,

```
df2 = data.frame(Id = c(1,2), 
                 Start = c("2021-06-01", "2021-08-01"), 
                 End = c("2021-08-15", "2021-09-15"))
```

In this example, the output would look like

```
  Id      Start        End Count
1  1 2021-06-01 2021-08-15     3
2  2 2021-08-01 2021-09-15     3
```

I have tried similar examples [How to get the number of counts between two dates in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279316/how-to-get-the-number-of-counts-between-two-dates-in-r) and
[count row if date falls within date range for all dates in series in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966129/count-row-if-date-falls-within-date-range-for-all-dates-in-series-in-r) without any success.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note: should Id 1 count be 4 in your expected output?

You can `group_by` your data and sum the dates that fall `%within%` the `interval` like this:

```r
df1 = data.frame(date = c("2021-07-31", "2021-08-01", "2021-08-12", "2021-08-14"))
df2 = data.frame(Id = c(1,2), 
                 Start = c("2021-06-01", "2021-08-01"), 
                 End = c("2021-08-15", "2021-09-15"))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df2 %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Count = sum(as_date(df1$date) %within% lubridate::interval(Start, End)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#> # Groups:   Id [2]
#>      Id Start      End        Count
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <int>
#> 1     1 2021-06-01 2021-08-15     4
#> 2     2 2021-08-01 2021-09-15     3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You are correct, not only can I not code, but I also can't count. Thank you

Comment: @wertisml, No problem! Could happen ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or with `base`:

```r
df2$Count <- apply(df2, 1, function(x) sum(as.Date(df1$date) %in% seq(as.Date(x["Start"]), as.Date(x["End"]), by = "1 day")))
```

Output:

```r
  Id      Start        End Count
1  1 2021-06-01 2021-08-15     4
2  2 2021-08-01 2021-09-15     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table::between` in `outer`.

```
f <- Vectorize(\(i, j) data.table::between(df1[i, 1L], df2[j, 2], df2[j, 3]))
transform(df2, count=colSums(outer(seq_len(nrow(df1)), seq_len(nrow(df2)), f)))
#   Id      Start        End count
# 1  1 2021-06-01 2021-08-15     4
# 2  2 2021-08-01 2021-09-15     3
```

Note, that `"Date"` format is required, so you may want to do this beforehand:

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.Date)
df2[-1] <- lapply(df2[-1], as.Date)
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18839, 18840, 18851, 18853), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Id = c(1, 2), Start = structure(c(18779, 18840
), class = "Date"), End = structure(c(18854, 18885), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```